# Create the path for saving the downloaded files

Tags: android, firebase-storage

Guys I solved the download of the file from Firebase Storage:

```
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

public class fragment_1 extends Fragment {

    Button bntDwn_1;
    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    StorageReference ref;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        bntDwn_1 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dwn_1);
        bntDwn_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                download();
            }
        });
    }

    public void download(){
        storageReference= firebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        ref = storageReference.child("fourapper_forpaper_1 (1).jpeg");
        ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String url = uri.toString();
                downloadFiles(getActivity(), Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "Sfondo", ".jpeg",url);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sfondo Salvato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0,200);
                toast.show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void downloadFiles(Context context, String destinationDirectory, String fileName, String fileExtension, String Url){
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(Url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName +fileExtension);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }
}
```

everything works perfectly download the required file, only that it saves everything in downloads, while I would like to download the photos in a precise folder inside the photos of the device so as to be easily found, so how do I save the downloaded file inside a path specified by me and precisely within the image gallery? thank you all

The file is saved in the following path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.nomeapp/files/Pictures/photo.jpeg while I would like to save them in: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/photo.jpeg

Comment: `it saves everything in downloads,` Really? One would not expect that using `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context`.

Comment: `in a precise folder inside the photos of the device` ??? Where would that be?

Comment: the photo that I download is shown only in the Android download folder, while in the photo gallery, which has every Android device is not present, and I would like to show it there in the image gallery in an album created on purpose then renamed with a name chosen by me.

Comment: You have not reacted on my first comment.

Comment: yes as I said save everything in download

Comment: That is not a reaction to my comment. You asked the manager to download to external files dir and it did not. It downloaded to a different path.

Comment: what a reaction I'm sorry I didn't understand what you mean, I'm new here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214961/discussion-between-fourapper-com-and-blackapps).

Comment: the file is saved in the following path: internal memory / android / data / com.nomeapp / files / camera / foto.jpeg
while I would like to save them in: internal memory / pictures / album name / photos.jpeg

Comment: What you mention are not file system paths. I wonder where you see such paths. As a programmer you should use a file explorer that shows you the real path like /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<appname>/files/.... And that is not the Download folder but the path of getExternalFilesDir. The normal download folder is /storage/emulated/0/Download.

Comment: the path of the saved file is the following: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.nomeapp/files/camera/foto.jpeg

Comment: instead I would like to save the downloaded photos in: / storage / emulated / 0 / Pictures / photos: jpeg, sorry but I'm new in programming for this I ask for advice, thanks

Answer (score 0):

test it

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                                "/" + pathSave);

            downloadFiles(getActivity(), "Sfondo", ".jpeg",file,url);
```

[image]

Comment: it also works but always saves it in the same path I instead would like to save it in: / storage / emulated / 0 / Pictures / photos: jpeg and then save it in / Pictures and not in: / Android / data

Comment: If that works then all you have to do is assigning "Pictures/Fourapper" to `pathSave'.

Comment: You can save in any direction you like

Comment: if you tell me how to create my own path then you do me a great favor since I'm trying them all but without changing anything, thanks

Comment: Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment./*any path android*/);

Comment: always gives me back the same thing

Comment: Wants are you save image always in pictures folder ??

Comment: yes I would like to save the images in this path: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/photo.jpeg

Comment: but instead everything is saved in the app folder

Comment: I would like to save the images in this path: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/photo.jpeg

Comment: Wants are you save image always in pictures folder ?? YES.